# RhoStudio build for iOS7 Simulator: "Gem rake not installed" error

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, rake, rhodes

I am trying to build a RhoStudio application for the iPhone-simulator on Mac OS X 10.9.1.

The build with XCode fails at

```
/bin/sh -c ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rhodes-4.0.1/platform/iphone/build/rhorunner.build/Release-iphonesimulator/rhorunner.build/Script-5C0442920EFBE79D0014E5C6.sh
[31mERROR: Gem rake is not installed, run `gem install rake` first. (B [m
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127
```

Within the script (Script-5C0442920EFBE79D0014E5C6.sh), there is a "source ~/.profile" call which seems to mess up the environment for rake. The error can be reproduced by opening a shell and executing the source command. If i don't source, there is no error for rake.

Also, if i try to gem install rake after the source command, there is a confirmation that it has been installed but the error still occurs.

Anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those issues where there are way too many specific factors involved to easily come up with a solution; I'm going through the ropes myself with Rhodes in 10.9. The problem is because Rhodes constantly is changing environments (it's a real mess) so your environment, which tracks the paths to your Ruby installations and Gems, will be very volatile. Here are some tips that might help you diagnose the issue:

1. Try running `gem which rake`, which shows you the absolute path of your rake gem as visible to the calling script. You can place this in one of your config files like `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` to test different contexts.
2. You can also use `gem env` to see a full printout of the gem's configuration for your environment, and just plain `env` shows you the system (shell) environment. Look very closely for the variables `GEM_PATH` AND `GEM_ROOT` which show you where Rubygems and your gem libs are searched for, respectively.
3. Keep in mind using `sudo` before install will affect where your gems are installed; this depends on where you installed Ruby, which ruby manager (for RVM look in `~/.rvm`) and whether or not you are using Bundler for instance.

Hope that helps. Also, if you are into Bash scripting I recently posted a tip for managing the environment paths that might help: https://coderwall.com/p/f_dlyg